# Why id of edit text doesn't show

Tags: kotlin

****Well, I am making a registration form in kotlin, but when I want to define edit text in MainActivity.kt, it does not offer me the id of my edit text as an option.****

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstName"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="207dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="207dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="473dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Comment: You mean you can't directly use it in Kotlin code as a property?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: OK, I'll point your question toward an existing question on the same topic.